# с помощью какого языка программирования и инструмента можно сделать приложение для андроид

Tags: android

с помощью какого языка программирования и инструмента можно сделать **приложение** для андроид?

Я знаю что есть Android Studio и если не ошибаюсь там можно писать на java но может есть что-то получше?

Comment: **с помощью  Java**

Comment: Получше - погуглить

Comment: Получше нет ничего, разве что писать на kotlin в том же Android Studio

Comment: Что значит получше? Может попроще?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение можно сделать с помощью любого языка в любой подходящей IDE.

Если делать нативно, то это будет Java/Kotlin в AndroidStudio.